# Are these two sentences pronounced the same?

Tags: pronunciation

Are these two sentences pronounced the same?
La donna ha il burro and La donna il burro.

Comment: Where have you seen "La donna il burro"? It's not a well constructed sentence, since it lacks of verb.

Comment: I am aware of that. I am asking if Ha is just not pronounced.

Comment: What makes you think that “ha” is not pronounced?

Comment: I never hear "ha" after donna. I thought you did not say donna-a il but rather donna il. Certain sounds seem to dissapear when people speak. Should I not just let certain sounds dissapear (Elision?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two phrases are pronounced differently, and the difference lies in a longer “a” and, in some marked articulations, perhaps in some kind of light (glottal?) stop between *donna* and *ha*: something like /la'dɔn:aʔail'bur:o/. Let's say, empirically, that in *La donna ha il burro* there is definitely one more syllable than in *La donna il burro*.

But we'd need here a professional phonetician.

Comment: I think I get it.